# How to solve the PyGSLIB library installation error?

Tags: python

I am trying to install the [PyGSLIB](https://opengeostat.github.io/pygslib/Tutorial.html) library and the following error is occurring:

```
(base) C:\Users\...> conda install -c opengeostat pygslib
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Determining conflicts:   0%|                                                                     | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pygslib -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

I installed Anaconda3 5.2.0

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipython
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

And library conflicts happen again

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c opengeostat pygslib
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3
  - defaults/win-64::astropy==3.0.2=py36h452e1ab_1
  - defaults/win-64::bkcharts==0.2=py36h7e685f7_0
  - defaults/win-64::blaze==0.11.3=py36h8a29ca5_0
  - defaults/win-64::bokeh==0.12.16=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::bottleneck==1.2.1=py36hd119dfa_0
  - defaults/win-64::dask==0.17.5=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::datashape==0.5.4=py36h5770b85_0
  - defaults/win-64::h5py==2.7.1=py36h3bdd7fb_2
  - defaults/win-64::imageio==2.3.0=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::matplotlib==2.2.2=py36h153e9ff_1
  - defaults/win-64::mkl_fft==1.0.1=py36h452e1ab_0
  - defaults/win-64::mkl_random==1.0.1=py36h9258bd6_0
  - defaults/win-64::numba==0.38.0=py36h830ac7b_0
  - defaults/win-64::numexpr==2.6.5=py36hcd2f87e_0
  - defaults/win-64::numpy==1.14.3=py36h9fa60d3_1
  - defaults/win-64::numpy-base==1.14.3=py36h555522e_1
  - defaults/win-64::odo==0.5.1=py36h7560279_0
  - defaults/win-64::pandas==0.23.0=py36h830ac7b_0
  - defaults/win-64::patsy==0.5.0=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pytables==3.4.3=py36he6f6034_1
  - defaults/win-64::pytest-arraydiff==0.2=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pytest-astropy==0.3.0=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pytest-doctestplus==0.1.3=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::pywavelets==0.5.2=py36hc649158_0
  - defaults/win-64::scikit-image==0.13.1=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - defaults/win-64::scikit-learn==0.19.1=py36h53aea1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::scipy==1.1.0=py36h672f292_0
  - defaults/win-64::seaborn==0.8.1=py36h9b69545_0
  - defaults/win-64::statsmodels==0.9.0=py36h452e1ab_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

I installed Python versions 3.5 and 3.6 and the same error occurs, could someone tell me a way to solve this problem or do you know any other library similar to the one that has the same purpose?

Comment: did the solution below solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your conda environment has `python3.8` installed but this not supported by looking at the requirements.
You can create a new conda environment by changing the python version or try to install it from [source](https://github.com/opengeostat/pygslib)

```
git clone https://github.com/opengeostat/pygslib.git
cd pygslib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I also notice such behaviour, where it doesn't matter what python version you install.

BAD:

```bash
conda install -c opengeostat pygslib
```

**CORRECT:**

```bash
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
conda install pygslib -c opengeostat -c conda-forge
```

In github, correct command is found. Wherease on website, was incorrect.